# How would you make a comma-separated string from a array of strings?

Tags: python, arrays, string

What would be your preferred way to concatenate strings from a sequence such that between every two consecutive pairs a comma is added. That is, how do you map, for instance, ['a', 'b', 'c'] to "'a','b','c'"?

```
status_arr = []
out: str
```

I need this transform for use in SQL `IN`

Comment: `', '.join(map(repr, status_arr))`

Comment: This is asking for opinions, not facts. `','.join(map(repr, status_arr))` does the job, is that what you meant to ask for?

Comment: Back in the early days of the site, "show YOUR way of doing X" questions were called "poll questions". There's a SO blog entry from ~2008ish, IRRC, describing why it was decided they were off-topic. ("What's the _best_ way of doing X?" questions likewise; whereas "how can I do X?", showing a failed attempt, is fine)

Comment: Mind, in general, this is a job your ORM should be doing for you; the SQLAlchemy query builder has had years of effort put into making its transforms reliable even in the face of deliberately hostile inputs; anything we give you here will not have that same robustness.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, The ORM is precisely me :)

Comment: Yes, and that's something I'm arguing is a bad idea. :) -- there are good reasons to avoid ORMs, but not a good reason to avoid a well-established query builder (unless you're the level of expert that wouldn't be asking this question), and the better-designed ORMs of today let you take only the query-builder bits and leave the object-relational-modeling alone if you don't want it. See SQLAlchemy Core as a solid foundation on top of which to build an ORM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use formatted string for each items in the list to enclose them by quotes, then join each by comma:

```py
>>> ','.join(f"'{x}'" for x in lst)
"'a','b','c'"
```

And, since you need to pass it to SQL IN operator, if having space after comma is not problematic, you can just pass the list to `str` then use slicing to get rid of opening and closing braces:

```py
>>> str(lst)[1:-1]
"'a', 'b', 'c'"

# If the values themselves contain single quote, 
# then you may encounter values with double quotes in the resulting string:

lst=["a'", 'b', 'c']
print(str(lst)[1:-1])
"a'", 'b', 'c'

# If this is the case, you can just stick with first answer
```

Comment: If you're writing your question to be suited-to-purpose for SQL IN, then how do you handle strings that have `'`s inside them? (SQL injection attacks are a thing, remember). `lst = [ "'; DROP TABLE USERS; -- ]` is a thing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy What a coincidence, I was actually updating the answer for that part

Comment: ...I don't see the update describing how to make sure the result is valid SQL syntax, or how to avoid injection attacks. Single quotes and double quotes aren't interchangeable in SQL the way they are in Python; in SQL, single quotes are used for data, and double quotes are used for names of database objects (tables, columns, etc) that can't be safely expressed unquoted.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the sample data doesn't contain any quote yet I added that as a note asking OP to stick with first approach if OP's expecting single quote in the strings in the list

Comment: Yes, but the first approach doesn't fix the security bugs; neither one does.

Comment: and the sample data not containing quotes is all the more reason to pay attention to them: people not thinking about and testing corner-case behavior is how you get security bugs permitting injection attacks when real-world data doesn't conform to your earlier expectations.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes I know that and that actually depends on how OP is passing SQL query, for e.g.: `execute` method of connection object from sqlite3 does let pass parameterized value, but the question is primarily concentrated at how to get the expected string value than to make query. And if we start dealing those, the question needs to be closed under missing details or clarity

Comment: @Charles Duffy, the subject is not "data base injection", you have absolutely no idea what I'm coding right now so your opinion on SQL injection is irrelevant.